# cannot load file 'content.js' chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a form in popup.html so that the user will be able to use the extension feature only after logged in. However I am getting the following error

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Failed
>   to load file: "content.js". 
>       at getPageDetails

This might be the reason, the login function could not be implemented because I have consoled in that function but it does not show up.

Here is the code

**popup.html**

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid wrapper">
      <div class="row center">
          <form id="login">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter email">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" id="login" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            <span id="status-display"></span>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="../js/popup.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
// This callback function is called when the content script has been
// injected and returned its results
function onPageDetailsReceived(pageDetails) {
    document.getElementById('email').value = pageDetails.email;
    document.getElementById('password').value = pageDetails.password;
}

// Global reference to the status display SPAN
var statusDisplay = null;

// POST the data to the server using XMLHttpRequest
function Login() {
    // Cancel the form submit
    event.preventDefault();

    // The URL to POST our data to
    var postUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:3008/users/sign_in';

    // Prepare the data to be POSTed by URLEncoding each field's contents
    var email = document.getElementById('email');
    var password = document.getElementById('password');
    var body = {
      email: email,
      password: password
    }
    const headers =  new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log('apiurl', postUrl, headers, body)
    fetch(postUrl, {
      method: 'POST',
      headers:headers,
      data: data
    })
    .then(function(response){
      console.log('respnse ------>', response)
      return response.json()
    })
    .then(function(data){
      console.log('data ------->', data)
    })
    .catch(function(err){
      console.log('err ---->', err)
    })
}

// When the popup HTML has loaded
window.addEventListener('load', function(evt) {
    // Cache a reference to the status display SPAN
    statusDisplay = document.getElementById('status-display');
    console.log('document', document.getElementById('login'))
    document.getElementById('login')
            .addEventListener('submit', Login);
    // Get the event page
    chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function(eventPage) {
        // Call the getPageInfo function in the event page, passing in
        // our onPageDetailsReceived function as the callback. This
        // injects content.js into the current tab's HTML
        eventPage.getPageDetails(onPageDetailsReceived);
    });
});
```

**eventPage.js**

```
// This function is called onload in the popup code
function getPageDetails(callback) {

    // Inject the content script into the current page
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: 'content.js' }); // could not find it says 
    // When a message is received from the content script
    chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) {
        // Call the callback function i.e onPageDetailsReceived in our case
        callback(message);
    });
};
```

Note: popup.js, eventPage.js, background.js all is in the same place

my manifest file looks like following

```
"permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "storage",
    "contextMenus",
    "http://*/*",
    "https://*/*"
  ],
  "options_page": "html/popup.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["js/eventPage.js", "js/background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches" : [
            "http://*/*", "https://*/*"
        ],
        "js" : [
            "js/content.js"
        ]
    }
],
```

Comment: 1) The path is js/content.js 2) no need for executeScript at all since you already declare content script injection in manifest.json

Comment: Thanks for your comment. If no need for executeScript, then should i only use chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message) { callback(message)}) ?

Comment: yes the error is solved but I thought that executeScript error restricted to listen the login() but even after that error being solved, the login function is not listened. Why is that so?

Comment: You didn't show your content.js but yeah one of the scripts should have onMessage listener. Also, to send to a content script you need chrome.tabs.sendMessage with a tab id. Don't forget to reload both the extension and the web page when you edit the content script code.